# Program agario in javaFx

Tags: javafx

I've been trying to make a game like agar.io but I'm stuck at the point where I can't figure out how to add all the dots in method Dots to the interface, can some one help me find out how to code it?

this is the main block

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
Random r = new Random();
Pane playfield;
static int score = 30;

List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Dots> allDots = new ArrayList<>();

Movement mouse = new Movement(0,0,0);

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // create containers
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    StackPane layerPane = new StackPane();

    // playfield for our Users
    playfield = new Pane();

    layerPane.getChildren().addAll(playfield);

    root.setCenter(layerPane);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 
            Settings.SCENE_WIDTH, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    /**if(r.nextInt(10) == 5){
        addDot();
    }**/
    // add 1 User
    addUser();
    if(r.nextInt(10)==5)
    {
        addDots();
    }

    // capture mouse position
    scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> {
        mouse.set(e.getX(), e.getY(), 0);
    });

    // process all Users
    AnimationTimer loop = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {

            // move
            allUsers.forEach((User) -> User.step(mouse));

            // check border
            allUsers.forEach(User::checkBoundaries);

            // update in fx scene
            allUsers.forEach(User::display);

        }
    };

    loop.start();

}

/**
 * Add single User to list of Users and to the playfield
 */
private void addUser() {

    User User = new User();

    allUsers.add(User);

    playfield.getChildren().add(User);

}
private void addDots(){
    int randX = r.nextInt(800);
    int randY = r.nextInt(600);
    Dots d = new Dots(randX, randY);
    allDots.add(d);
    playfield.getChildren().add(d);

}
/**private void addDot() {
    Circle a = new Circle();
    int randX = r.nextInt(800);
    int randY = r.nextInt(600);
    Dot d = new Dot(randX,randY);
    synchronized(dots){
        dots.add(d);
    }
    playfield.getChildren().add(d);
}**/

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Settings

```
public class Settings {

public static double SCENE_WIDTH = 800;
public static double SCENE_HEIGHT = 600;

}
```

Movement

```
public class Movement {

public double x;
public double y;
public double z;

public Movement(double x, double y, double z) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public void normalize() {
    double m = mag(); 
    if (m != 0 && m != 1) { 
      div(m); 
    } 
}

public void div(double value) {
    x /= value;
    y /= value;
    z /= value;
}

public void mult(double value) {
    x *= value;
    y *= value;
    z *= value;
}

public void add(Movement v) {
    x += v.x;
    y += v.y;
    z += v.z;
}

public void sub(Movement v) {
    x -= v.x;
    y -= v.y;
    z -= v.z;
}

public void limit(float max) {
    if (mag() > max) {
        normalize();
        mult(max);
    }
}

public double mag() {
    return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
}

public static Movement sub(Movement v1, Movement v2) {
    return sub(v1, v2, null);
}

public static Movement sub(Movement v1, Movement v2, Movement target) {
    if (target == null) {
        target = new Movement(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y, v1.z - v2.z);
    } else {
        target.set(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y, v1.z - v2.z);
    }
    return target;
}

public void set(double x, double y, double z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}
```

Dots

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class Dots extends Pane{
public int x;
public int y;
private static Random random = new Random();
int size = 10;
Circle circle;

public Dots(int x, int y) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    circle = new Circle(this.x, this.y, size);
    circle.setCenterX(size);
    circle.setCenterY(size);
    circle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    circle.setFill(Color.CYAN);
    getChildren().add(circle);

  }

}
```

Users

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class Dots extends Pane{
  public int x;
  public int y;
  private static Random random = new Random();
  int size = 10;
  Circle circle;

  public Dots(int x, int y) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    circle = new Circle(this.x, this.y, size);
    circle.setCenterX(size);
    circle.setCenterY(size);
    circle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    circle.setFill(Color.CYAN);
    getChildren().add(circle);

    }

}
```